# Python numpy, сортировка

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Есть многомерный массив точек (`boxes`), как повторить такую сортировку:

```
for (startXa, startYa, endXa, endYa) in boxes:
    startX = startX if startX < startXa else startXa
    startY = startY if startY < startYa else startYa

    endX = endX if endX > endXa else endXa
    endY = endY if endY > endYa else endYa
```

Comment: уточните, что имеется ввиду под "повторить такую сортировку"?.. особенно про "повторить" и где "сортировка" ;)

Comment: Я тоже ничего не понял )  Приведите пример исходных данных и что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: Функция вычисляет bounding box для прямоугольников на плоскости.

Comment: Есть массив координат. Нужно между четырьмя точкам нарисовать квадрат, чтобы все остальные вошли в площадь этого квадрата. Если прямо - нейронка возвращает координаты зон, где может быть текст. Мне нужно вырезать их все, как одно изображение, и отправить в tesseract. Сделал циклом (приведен выше), но хотелось бы как-то нормально.

Comment: @Lasna1, сам по себе код нормальный, оптимизировать тут имеет смысл только если именно в этом месте тормозит.

Comment: Нормальный? Я думал, у numpy есть api для сортировки.

Comment: В вашем коде нет сортировки, просто нахождение максимальных/минимальных значений.

Comment: Да, но это можно сделать средствами api?

Comment: @Lasna1 оставьте как есть, тут нечего оптимизировать средствами какого-то api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже правильно заметили, тут нет сортировки.

```
for (startXa, startYa, endXa, endYa) in boxes:
    startX=np.min(startX, startXa)
    startY=np.min(startY, startYa)
    endX=np.max(endX, endXa)
    endY=np.max(endY, endYa)
```

Можно вообще оботись без for, если boxes - np.array, а не список.